# Saving a property of an Hibernate entity with the value from a database function

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have an Hibernate entity which has a `java.util.Date` property. Instead of setting the property value  to `new Date()` on my entity and then saving with Hibernate, I would like to make the database set the date through a SYSDATE() function. I want this because I can't rely on the date set by the client, because it is a swing app. I can only trust on the time taken from the database.

I have thought of some options, but both seem quite poor:

- Ask the database for the current time, set it on my object and then save. (expensive)
- Create an Hibernate insert statement and pass the parameters manually. (subverts the purpose of Hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate allows you to have DB generated columns, check the [Generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated) Hibernate documentation.

You database should have a DEFAULT SYSDATE configuration.

Check [this example](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-generated-hibernate) for a complete solution.

Comment: Generated properties are just a way to make Hibernate get the generated value for you. The `DEFAULT SYSDATE` made the trick I wanted. I used the `insert="false"` but disabled the `generated="insert"` because I don't need the generated value.